# Xml written twice while appending

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, aiml

When trying to append an existing xml file using **xml.etree.ElementTree**. The sub elements are written twice. Is there any way we can overcome this.

This is my current code:

```
with open('filename.aiml',"a+") as f:
                        tree=ET.parse(f)
                        root=tree.getroot()
                        rootTag=root.find('.')
                        category=ET.SubElement(rootTag,'category')
                        pattern=ET.SubElement(category,'pattern')
                        pattern.text=input_text.upper()
                        template=ET.SubElement(category,'template')
                        template.text=response
                        root.append(category)
                        tree.write(open("filename.aiml","w+"),encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

XML before written:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<aiml version="1.0">
<category>
<pattern>WHAT IS DEEP LEARNING</pattern>
<template>Deep learning (also known as deep structured learning or hierarchical learning) is part of a broader family of machine learning methods based on learning data representations, as opposed to task-specific algorithms.</template>
</category>
```

XML after written:

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
    <aiml version="1.0">
    <category>
    <pattern>WHAT IS DEEP LEARNING</pattern>
    <template>Deep learning (also known as deep structured learning or hierarchical learning) is part of a broader family of machine learning methods based on learning data representations, as opposed to task-specific algorithms.</template>
    </category>
 <category>
<pattern>WHAT IS PROOF OF CONCEPT</pattern>
<template>Proof of Concept (PoC) is a realization of a certain method or idea in order to demonstrate its feasibility.</template>
</category>
<category><pattern>TELL ME ABOUT POC</pattern>
<template>Proof of Concept (PoC) is a realization of a certain method or idea in order to demonstrate its feasibility</template>
</category>
<category><pattern>WHAT IS PROOF OF CONCEPT</pattern>
<template>Proof of Concept (PoC) is a realization of a certain method or idea in order to demonstrate its feasibility</template>
</category>
<category><pattern>TELL ME ABOUT POC</pattern>
<template>Proof of Concept (PoC) is a realization of a certain method or idea in order to demonstrate its feasibility.</template></category>
```

Comment: Never read XML files with `open()`. Use `tree = ET.parse('path/to/file')`. The latter handles file encodings properly, the former does not. And the latter  is shorter, too. That being said, you cannot "append" to an XML file. Load the tree, modify the tree, save the tree.

Comment: @Tomalak I need to add the new elements into an existing XML file. But when i dont use `tree.write(open("filename.aiml","w+"),encoding='ISO-8859-1')` it shows XML parse error

Comment: Are you even reading what I have said? I said **you cannot append to an XML file**.

Comment: actually the above code can be used to **append to an existing xml file** . The only problem is that the sub elements gets written twice.

Comment: No, it can't. But apparently you know what you are doing, so go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you xml is throwing errors on parsing , so i would go with an example here.

Parse your data

```
root= ET.XML(filename)
```

do your modifications whatever you want (adding nodes,values)
e.g. from the python document

```
for rank in root.iter('rank'):
...     new_rank = int(rank.text) + 1
...     rank.text = str(new_rank)
...     rank.set('updated', 'yes')
```

all the changes are saved to root element.

**Write it to a xml file**

you need to pass root to ET.ElementTree(), that will save all your previous changes and would write to xml

```
with open('d:\output.xml', 'wb') as file:
    ET.ElementTree(root).write(file, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```